# How to access elements in NPZ file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, element

I am trying to access elements of NPZ file using code:

```
with np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/data_new.npz',allow_pickle=True) as data:
    a = data['image_features']
    print(a)
```

It shows output:

```
{'199476': array([[194.04953 , 184.43268 , 639.      , 425.29    ],
       [318.4676  ,  15.762019, 421.1574  , 253.30766 ],
       [219.09093 , 258.60388 , 452.2419  , 384.9459  ],
       [  0.      ,  47.438347, 480.05542 , 425.29    ],
       [  0.      ,   0.      , 363.19708 , 279.19672 ],
       [148.79245 ,   0.      , 639.      , 210.85545 ],
       [  0.      ,   0.      , 258.4733  , 334.14972 ],
       [158.05794 , 320.6399  , 501.2573  , 425.29    ],
       [452.9518  ,   0.      , 639.      , 165.6061  ],
       [  0.      , 255.72142 , 407.57358 , 425.29    ],
       [  0.      ,  22.864079, 140.49962 , 183.17285 ],
       [361.452   , 212.55576 , 639.      , 388.3693  ],
       [554.8864  ,   0.      , 639.      , 101.53771 ],
       [404.05536 , 185.98639 , 578.6646  , 228.58595 ],
       [  0.      , 140.13982 , 123.02028 , 159.72864 ],
       [244.72183 , 250.01173 , 433.06476 , 369.9772  ],
       [128.43852 , 236.70012 , 473.5753  , 369.5989  ],
       [ 52.357124,  39.874092,  75.0104  ,  59.43568 ],
       [144.01859 , 125.3886  , 227.6077  , 204.53206 ],
       [236.9453  ,   0.      , 338.77094 , 123.54699 ],
       [543.54865 , 229.0633  , 627.2213  , 327.51517 ],
       [ 30.98246 , 158.72491 , 326.61508 , 277.84668 ],
       [338.70795 ,  80.93436 , 405.304   , 245.34258 ],
       [151.49304 , 129.96037 , 177.9043  , 200.56523 ],
       [ 94.5418  , 197.5486  , 316.87244 , 253.77058 ],
       [354.94272 ,   0.      , 464.82605 , 226.65717 ],
       [298.1035  , 156.23262 , 315.1587  , 191.82831 ],
       [414.6097  , 133.66512 , 639.      , 222.94992 ],
       [ 95.302864,  92.23008 , 126.67215 , 141.62634 ],
       [184.92436 , 133.2275  , 211.72473 , 199.64825 ],
       [446.2884  , 203.46916 , 631.4623  , 366.25217 ],
       [ 73.46329 , 189.02185 , 332.6924  , 204.93848 ],
       [575.9691  , 204.70457 , 639.      , 244.41171 ],
       [  9.975321, 115.68157 ,  88.33198 , 147.83711 ]], dtype=float32), '191749': array([[154.99905 , 258.4661  , 382.08    ,
639.36    ],
       [ 80.65501 , 117.60948 , 156.59785 , 194.87871 ],
       [ 13.431582,   0.      , 382.08    , 232.27637 ],
       [  0.      , 441.22034 , 346.04956 , 639.36    ],
       [ 83.3774  ,  37.678146, 382.08    , 385.55423 ],
       [134.28326 ,   0.      , 287.05    , 188.16321 ],
       [105.51391 ,  92.20693 , 356.94604 , 553.49445 ],
```

I tried to Check the type of **a** by using

```
type(a)
```

it displays:

> numpy.ndarray

I want to access the elements of this file. How can I do that?

Comment: `a = np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/data_new.npz',allow_pickle=True)` the use `element = a['image_features']` then you have the element ... am i missing something

Comment: if you want you can use indexing to access the axes like `element[index in 3_dim]`

Comment: Treat `.npz` as an opaque file format that cannot be meaningfully accessed at the byte level. That might not be 100% true, but writing your own implementation of `np.load()` is a pretty ambitious project for a novice.

Comment: @HSa element = a['image_features'] displays the same output as above. I want to access the float values.

Also, I didn't understand how do you mean should I use  " element[index in 3_dim]"

Comment: use `element.shape` to find a shape of element the if it was 2d use **2d dimensional coordinate** if it was 3d use **3d dimensional coordinate**

Comment: you can use list comprehension for loading the data seperated like `list = [a[item] for item in a]`

Comment: See the `{199476:...`.  That's a `dict` and `key`

Comment: But you may need to first use `adict=a.item()`, if `a` is a single element object dtype array.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks alot. After using `adict=a.item()` I am able to get to "199476" and later lists